# Converting configuration properties to enum values

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have a configuration file which contains this line:

```
login.mode=PASSWORD
```

and an enum

```
public enum LoginMode {
PASSWORD, NOT_PASSWORD, OTHER }
```

and a spring bean

```
<bean id="environment" class="a.b.c.Environment" init-method="init">
  <property name="loginMode" value="${login.mode}"/>
</bean>
```

and of course a bean class

```
public class Environment {
    private LoginMode loginMode;

    public LoginMode getLoginMode() {
        return loginMode;
    }

    public void setLoginMode(LoginMode loginMode) {
        this.loginMode = loginMode;
    }
}
```

How can i convert the property of the configuration file (which is a String) into the corresponding enum value of LoginMode?

EDIT: i know how to get the enum value of a string input, but the issue is another one:
If i try this:

```
public class Environment {
    private LoginMode loginMode;

    public LoginMode getLoginMode() {
        return loginMode;
    }

    public void setLoginMode(String loginMode) {
        this.loginMode = LoginMode.valueOf(loginMode);
    }
}
```

spring is complaining about getter and setter not having the same input and output type.

```
Bean property 'loginMode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the    parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Convert String to enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum)

Comment: it is not a duplicate of that question, see edit.

Comment: so maybe that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030974/spring-how-do-i-inject-enum-in-spring-configuration will help?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the answer was quite simple... ill post it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Spring automatically converts input Strings to the corresponding valueOf of the desired enum.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by

```
LoginMode.valueOf("someString");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 LoginMode.valueOf(valueOfProperty);
```

EDIT:
Try using converter
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch05s05.html
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/83191-custom-enum-string-converters

EDIT2:
also check this:
[How assign bean's property an Enum value in Spring config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516771/how-assign-beans-property-an-enum-value-in-spring-config-file)

Comment: where would i have to convert the string? in the bean configuration or in the environment class?